# Allow any visitor to update or insert records?

Tags: meteor

So I am trying to get the leaderboard example to work with removing the insecure package, how do I allow any visitor to the site to update the score.

this is what I have so far in my collections folder, what do i put next to update?

```
 Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");

 Players.allow({
   update:
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function in the call to allow returns true, the update will be accepted.

```js
Players.allow({
    update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier){
        // Accept update by returning true.
        // Deny update by returning false. 
    }
});
```

If you just want to allow the users to update the score-field, this is where you should validate it. You can for example check so the parameter `modifier` is equal to `{$inc: {score: 5}}`, which is what is used on the client side (and expected here on the server side).

Note: allow (and deny) calls can be used in a more advanced way than described here. Check the documentation.